# Two factor authentication using SHIRO

Tags: authentication, shiro, multi-factor-authentication

I am implementing two factor authentication in my web project. we are using SHIRO for authentication and authorization.
Once a user is logged in (SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(subjectToken);)
user is able to open any page.
I want to ask user a PIN sent on his mobile to complete authentication. On the next page after login, if user does not enter PIN and directly open home page by writing URL, he/she can bypass PIN validation.
I have checked roleRedirect and authenticationRedirect but request does not come in these filters.
Can Anyone tell me what is the proper way to implement two factor using SHIRO.

Answer (score 0):

Shiro does not have support for two factor auth yet.  So you would need to handle the tracking of state between the initial password login and the second factor.  Or you could manage this using authorization. Where a user is logged in once they enter a valid password, but they do not have a given permission '2factor'.  If this permission is not present, you could redirect to your 2nd factor page, once entered you could grant the user the '2facter' permission.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a filter and check where session has otpverified variable true or not like we do generally.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // place your code here

        // pass the request along the filter chain
        //System.out.println(enabled);
            if(enabled){
            if(SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal()!=null){
                if(request instanceof HttpServletRequest ){
                    HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
                    LoggedInUser user =  (LoggedInUser) session.getAttribute("userinfo");
                    String url = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString();
                    //System.out.println("url is "+ url +" subject is: "+ SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated());

                    if( SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated() && !url.contains("public") && !user.isOTPverified()){



                        if(user.getOTP() == null)
                            {

                                if(user.getTOTPSecret()!=null && user.getTOTPSecret().length()>0)
                                {
                                    user.setOTP("TOTP");
                                }else
                                {
                                    user.setOTP(OTPUtils.generateOTP());
                                    new SendMail().send("abc@c.com", "OTP for accessing ","OTP is "+ user.getOTP(), 1, new String[] {});
                                }

                            }
                        //user.setOTPverified(true);                        
                        ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestDispatcher("OTPVerify.jsp").forward(request, response);

                        return;
                    }
                }
            }


            }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```